# How to mimic ref and get in angular firestore unit tests

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angular-test, angular-unit-test

I am trying to mock firestore in my angular app. I have found [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54109970/how-to-test-firestore-methods) and had already done something similar. However, I need to mock the get function. This function is used in conjunction with the ref parameter, which is something that I don't really grasp in firestore.

Here is part of my test:

```
beforeEach(() => {

    const fakeAFS = jasmine.createSpyObj( 'AngularFirestore', [ 'collection' ]);
    
    fakeAFS.collection.and.returnValue(jasmine.createSpyObj( 'collection', [ 'doc', 'snapshotChanges', 'valueChanges' ]));
    fakeAFS.collection().doc.and.returnValue(jasmine.createSpyObj( 'doc', ['valueChanges', 'ref', 'get']));
    fakeAFS.collection().doc().ref.and.returnValue(jasmine.createSpyObj( 'ref', ['get']));
    fakeAFS.collection().doc().ref.get.and.returnValue( of('FakeDocument'));
    

    fakeAFS.collection().doc().valueChanges.and.returnValue( of('FakeDocument'));

    //fakeAFS.collection().doc().update.and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(null));

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [ ],
    providers: [ { provide : AngularFirestore,   useValue : fakeAFS },
                 { provide : UserService,       useValue : mockUserServ } ]
    });

    service = TestBed.inject(ProfileService);

});
```

Here is the service portion that I am trying to mock.

```
        var docRef = this.afs.collection("users").doc(userId);

        docRef.ref.get().then((doc) => {

            if (doc.exists) {
                this.profileStatus.next(doc.data()); 

            } else {

                console.log('I am here.');

                this.afs.collection('users', ref => ref.where('userName', '==', userId))
                .get()
                .subscribe(result=> {
                    result.forEach((doc) => {
                        this.profileStatus.next(doc.data()); 
                    }); 
                });

            }
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log("Error getting document:", error);
        });
```

As you can see, there ref.get portion is what is causing troubles. Any suggestions on how to handle this?

Comment: What exactly are your trying to achieve with the `.ref`, instead of just doing `docRef.get()?`

Comment: That is how it is done in the examples. It is never really explained.